# TypeScript `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` for dynamic indexes

Tags: typescript

Checkout [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=false#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4EkwBMCmAPACgEoAuRMEZAIxwCdEBvAKEUVpyhFqQEYBuJgF8mTCAgDOURDGz4yFanUQBeFBlmEiAsWEmI4VAFZkASjjG0sAHgU1aAGkSTaMgOYA+FY0ECmMYIgE4LjAMjhYKsqqBoYA2jK4eAC6RPpG8RpJXgDkAO4AFgCGUDgAbnTZAjEZiUkAdJKFtFDiAOowUPkEedlaTEA) code.

As you see, despite checking index access for `undefined`, we still get an error.
Why this is happening? Is this intended or is a bug?

If we remove the function and use a static number, we don't get any error.

Comment: Please [edit] to put your code directly in the question as text; a link to an IDE demo is a nice supplement but doesn't suffice by itself.